# Calculating Interest Rates Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I Need to calculate the compund interest rate so, lets say I have a Dataframe like that:

```
   days
1   10
2   15
3   20
```

What I want to get is (suppose the interest rate is 1% every day:

```
    days   interst rate
1   10     10,46%
2   15     16,10%
3   20     22,02%
```

My code is as follows:

```
def inclusao_juros (x):
    dias = df_arrumada_4['Prazo Medio']
    return ((1.0009723)^dias)-1

df_arrumada_4['juros_acumulado'] = df_arrumada_4['Prazo Medio'].apply(inclusao_juros)
```

What should I do??? Tks

Comment: `(1.0009723)^dias` _does not_ raise `1.0009723` to the power of `dias`.

Comment: In input data is column `Prazo Medio` ?

Comment: Yes, input is Prazo Medio (translating is number of days). I need to raise 1.0009723 to the power of dias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html):

```
df['new'] = np.power(1.01, df['days']) - 1
print (df)
   days       new
1    10  0.104622
2    15  0.160969
3    20  0.220190
```

Comment: You got it ! the numpy is the best :-)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
pd.Series([1.01]*len(df)).pow(df.reset_index().days,0).sub(1)
Out[695]: 
0    0.104622
1    0.160969
2    0.220190
dtype: float64
```

Jez's : `pd.Series([1.01]*len(df),index=df.index).pow(df.days,0).sub(1)`

Or using your `apply`

```
df.days.apply(lambda x: 1.01**x -1)
Out[697]: 
1    0.104622
2    0.160969
3    0.220190
Name: days, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @jezrael pow is index sensitive, and he has the index from 1 to 3 not 0 to 2 ,if do not reset the result will have 4 row and two of them  are NaN

Comment: @jezrael I think yours is much better :-)

Comment: Be free add to answer ;)

Comment: `df.days.apply(lambda x: 1.01**x) - 1` ?

Comment: @jezrael haha , forget about the -1 :-)